Problem loading internal css with Spring Security 6 and Thymeleaf
My code below, login page doesn't load css resources, if I disable Spring Security it loads:
\\src\\main\\resources\\static\\assets\\css\\login.css
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize

                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/equipment/").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/employees/new").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/employees").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/index").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/resources/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .rememberMe(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .logout((logout) -> logout
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login"));
        return http.build();
    }

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
        .ignoring()
        .requestMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**","/vendor/**","/fonts/**");
    }
}

Login Page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="pt-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NYL SOAPP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/assets/css/login.css}">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
</div>

</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>

My code below, login page doesn't load css resources, if I disable Spring Security it loads:
\src\main\resources\static\assets\css\login.css
So it is not problem with the link
